# Is an ISO or EXE download available for Visual Web Developer 11 Beta?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-web-developer, visual-studio-2012

Am I able to download the Visual Web Developer 11 Beta ISO or EXE?

I have a very bad Internet connection that drops out all the time, so I would like to download it at a friend’s place and not use the Web Platform Installer if it can be helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys but I found it here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28975 VS11_BETA_ULT_ENU.iso is the one.

Now I have it all up and running i'm not sure if I like it!!!

Comment: Just a word of warning though, once I installed this it took over certain ports and I was unable to find localhost without doing a complete systems restore. has anyone else faced that?

Comment: Hmm, no. I just installed it myself on Server 2008 R2 and didn't have any issues. What do you mean by "took over certain ports"? Do you mean that it added exceptions to your Windows Firewall? Consider posting a new question about this behavior if you can reproduce it.

Answer (score 3):

If you are an MSDN subscriber, you should be able to download the ISO from the [MSDN Subscriber Downloads page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/subscriptions/downloads/). But I suppose that you are not, considering that you're asking this question!

Unfortunately, I cannot find an official ISO of Visual Web Developer 11 Beta that is publically available on Microsoft's website.

However, you can [download an ISO of any of the 4 editions of Visual Studio 11 here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#vs), which would include all of the functionality of Visual Web Developer. For example, the [Professional version is available here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/downloads#professional). The download is slightly larger, but if the Internet connection is stable, that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could use internet download manager, even if your connection drops out the downloaded parts would not be corrupted.

Comment: sure, it helps on slow connections, but only if source allows resumable downloads.